# How do I enable iptables in a Beaker recipe?

Tags: beaker-testing

In a default RHEL6.5 install, iptables is configured (rules exist in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`) and the service is enabled. But in a Beaker recipe, iptables is not running and not configured. `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` does not exist and all ports are open.

Why is it different in a Beaker recipe? How do I enable iptables?

(This is based on a question originally asked 2014-03-27 by Ondrej Ptak on a mailing list.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beaker disables the firewall by default to make multi-host testing easier.

The generated kickstart contains `firewall --disabled` which causes Anaconda to not configure or enable iptables (see [`firewall` in the Anaconda docs](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html#idp3902688)).

You can override the default behaviour by setting the `firewall` ksmeta variable for your recipe. For example, to only open ports 22, 80, and 8080:

```
<recipe ks_meta="firewall=ssh:tcp,http:tcp,8080:tcp">
    ...
```

Refer to the [Kickstart metadata](https://beaker-project.org/docs/user-guide/customizing-installation.html#kickstart-metadata) section in Beaker's docs.